# getElementsByName does not work and return zero length

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname

I have a valid `index.htm` file that contains 6 `<a>` tags, but when I run the code it just returns `0` length instead of `6`.

```
var myLinks = document.getElementsByName("a");
console.log("Links:", myLinks.length);
```

index.htm:

```
<body>
    <a href="#">link1</a>    <a href="#">link2</a>    <a href="#">link3</a>
    <a href="#">link4</a>    <a href="#">link5</a>    <a href="#">link6</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you using `getElementsByName` (title), `getElementsByClassName` (question), or `getElementsByTagName` (tag), because you can't seem to make up your mind.

Comment: Your Codeexample sais: "...ByClassName" instead of "...ByTagName", so no wonder...

Comment: Assuming that you just made several typos and use the correct tag, are you executing your JS code before the `<a>` are rendered on the page?

Answer (score 4):

The function `document.getElementsByName('some')` (from the question title) would recover *n* elements with that `name` attribute:

```
<a name='some'>...</a>
<a name='some'>...</a>
<a name='some'>...</a>
```

The function `document.getElementsByClassName('some')` (from the question code) would recover *n* elements with that `class` attribute:

```
<a class='some'>...</a>
<a class='some'>...</a>
<a class='some'>...</a>
```

The function `document.getElementsByTagName('a')` (seems to be what the OP want) would recover *n* elements of that type:

```
<a>...</a>
<a>...</a>
<a>...</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

`document.getElementsByClassName("a")` retrieves all elements whose *css class* name is `a`, e.g. `<div class="a">`.

`document.getElementsByName("a")` retrieves all elements whose `name` attribute is `a`, e.g. `<div name="a">`.

I think you're looking for `document.getElementsByTagName("a")`, which you've even tagged it with...!

Comment: I just done the wrong copy and past this is my code:var myLinks = var myLinks = document.getElementsByName("a");
console.log("Links:", myLinks.length);

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted someone cares to explain?

Comment: @user3066821: Please fix the question. There's an "edit" link. Right now, the question is not answerable because it's completely random.

Comment: @adeel_s I wonder the same thing. The question was weird, but I'm not sure what offence people have with my answer...